# when using "group_by" in a query, select an element from each group

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I was wondering how to extract an arbitrary element from a class when querying with "group by". For example:

```
class Post(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    created = Column(DateTime)
    comments = Column(Integer)
    creator = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    anonymous = Column(Boolean)

class User(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

How would I create a query that outputs:

```
creator | total number of comments made on the creator's post | the time of the creator's last post

creator | total number of comments made on the creator's post | if any of the posts are anonymous
```

Basic query would be:

```
session = DBSession()
commsum = session.query(Post.creator, func.sum(Post.comments).label('totalcomments')).\
    group_by(Post.creator).subquery()
return session.query(User, commsum.c.totalcomments).\
    join(commsum, commsum.c.creator == User.id).all()
```

What if I wanted to return 1) the newest date of all rows in each group_by(Post.creator) or 2) if any of the rows had anonymous == True.

Comment: What have you got at the moment? What have you tried? (Please update your question with this info.)

Comment: haven't tried anything yet, busy working on other tasks. i was just looking for a solution but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you should be able to do something like:

```
SELECT Post.creator, 
       sum(Post.comments) total_comments
       max(Post.Created) latest_post
       max(Post.anonymous) any_anonymous
FROM Post
GROUP BY Post.creator
```